# Identity-based blob triggers for Azure functions fail locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-blob-trigger

## Context

A blob triggered function written in Java:

```
@FunctionName("blob")
public String execute(
    @BlobTrigger(name = "test", path = "testcontainer/{name}", connection = "BlobTriggerConnection")
    String content, ExecutionContext context) {
    // function's code
}
```

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger#identity-based-connections), to use identity based triggers, following App Settings entries must be created:

- `BlobTriggerConnection__blobServiceUri`
- `BlobTriggerConnection__queueServiceUri`
- `BlobTriggerConnection__credential`

Moreover, function's identity must have correct permissions on the blob storage.

I've done that in Azure and it works well.

## Problem

However, running the function locally along with `Azurite` fails with the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.blob'. Microsoft.Extensions.Azure: Unable to find matching constructor while trying to create an instance of BlobServiceClient.
Expected one of the follow sets of configuration parameters:
1. connectionString
2. serviceUri
3. serviceUri, credential:accountName, credential:accountKey
4. serviceUri, credential:signature
5. serviceUri

Found the following configuration keys: queueServiceUri, credential, blobServiceUri.
```

**It is as if identity based triggers aren't supported.**

`local.settings.json` file's content:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "BlobTriggerConnection__blobServiceUri": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1:10000",
    "BlobTriggerConnection__credential": "managedidentity",
    "BlobTriggerConnection__queueServiceUri": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1:10001"
  }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of tools locally:

```
> brew search azure-functions-core-tools

azure/functions/azure-functions-core-tools@4
```

I should point out that this is a MacBook with intel's chipset.

Comment: have you tried setting up just this one: `BlobTriggerConnection__serviceUri` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `local.settings.json` to resolve your issue:

```
"AzureWebJobsblobConnection__serviceUri":"https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net"
```

Make sure you add this too

```
"blobConnection__serviceUri ":"https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net"
```

and this is how the `.cs` file will look:

```
public void Run([BlobTrigger("%blobName%", Connection = "blobConnection")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Wow, this is the only comment that worked for me. Nowhere in the MS docs or Github issue forums shows this. Thank you!!